# Invalid for key after migration from MagentoEE to CE

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I have an issue with **Magento 1.9** as I migrated my website from Magento
EE to Magento CE 1.9, everything is going well but when registration
I got this error message `Invalid form key` and when I logging with
Facebook plugin I got `404 page not found`.

Could you please support me ?

Comment: Version is Magento1.9.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 1.9.3.7 or apply SUPEE-10415 to fix the `Invalid form key error`.

This error was introduced in Magento 1.9.3.6.